# Dimension errors in neural network in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a neural network where I merge/concatenate a fully connected neural network with a convolution neural network. But when I fit the model, I get the following error:

> ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of
>   samples. Got array shapes: [(1, 100, 60, 4500), (100, 4500)]

I have two different inputs:

1. **image**(dimensions: 1,100,60,4500) where 1 is the channel, 100: # of sample, 60*4500 (dimension of my image). This goes to my convolution neural network
2. **positions**(dimensions: 100,4500): where 100 refers to samples.

Dimension for my output is 100,2.

The code for my neural network is:

```
###Convolution neural network
b1 = Sequential()
b1.add(Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',data_format='channels_first',
              input_shape=(100,60,4500)))
b1.add(Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
b1.add(Dropout(0.2))

b1.add(Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
b1.add(Dropout(0.2))


b1.add(Flatten())
b1.summary()

###Fully connected feed forward neural network
b2 = Sequential()
b2.add(Dense(64, input_shape = (4500,), activation='relu'))
b2.add(Dropout(0.1))
b2.summary()

model = Sequential()

###Concatenating the two networks
concat = concatenate([b1.output, b2.output], axis=-1)

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(concat)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([b1.input, b2.input], [output])

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit([image, positions], Ytest, batch_size=10,
              epochs=1,
              verbose=1)
```

Also, the reason why my 'image' array is 4 dimensional is because in the beginning it was just (100,60,4500) but then I ran into the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_10_input to
>   have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 60, 4500)

And upon googling I found out that it expects # of channels as an input too. And after I added the # of channel, this error went away but then I ran into the other error that I mentioned in the beginning.

So can someone tell me how to solve for the error (the one I specified in the beginning)? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `input_shape=(100,60,4500)` to `(1, 60, 4500)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You number of samples (batch size) should always be the first dimension. So, your data should have shape `(100, 1, 60, 4500)` for image and `(100, 4500)` for positions. The argument `channels_first` for the Conv2D layer means that the channels is the first non-batch dimension.

You also need to change the input shape to `(1, 60, 4500)` in the first Conv2D layer.

Comment: I changed the shape, but then I run into the following error that I mentioned before:** ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_13_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 60, 4500)** . My image shape is now (100,1,60,4500) and positions is the same (100,4500)

Comment: DId you also change `input_shape`?

Comment: It is working for me with this dummy data: `image = np.random.rand(100,1,60,4500)`, 
`positions = np.random.rand(100,4500)`,
`Ytest = np.random.randint(2, size=(100,2))`

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to mix `Sequential` and `Functional API`.

You can implement the model like this

```
i1 = Input(shape=(1, 60, 4500))

c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',data_format='channels_first')(i1)
c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = Flatten()(c1)

i2 = Input(shape=(4500, ))
c2 = Dense(64, input_shape = (4500,), activation='relu')(i2)
c2 = Dropout(0.2)(c2)

c = concatenate([c1, c2])

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(c)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([i1, i2], [output])

model.summary()
```

Note the shape of `i1` is `shape=(1, 60, 4500)`. You have set `data_format='channels_first'` in Conv2D layer hence you need `1` in the beginning.

Compiled the model like this

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Placeholder data

```
import numpy as np

X_img = np.zeros((100, 1, 60, 4500))
X_pos = np.ones((100, 4500))
Y = np.zeros((100, 2))
```

Training

```
history = model.fit([X_img, X_pos], Y, batch_size=1,
              epochs=1,
              verbose=1)
```